# How do I fix this error message: "Undeclared identifier"?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

Here is the code:

```
 EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc]
                       initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskEvent];
NSArray *eventCalendars = [store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

NSDate *monday, *sunday;
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:monday
                                           endDate:sunday
                                         calendars:eventCalendars];
NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Events this week:");
for (EKEvent *event in events) {
    NSLog(@"%@ - starts at %@", event.title, event.startDate);
}
```

I am getting an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'EKEntityMaskEvent'"
and Use of undeclared identifier 'EKEntityTypeEvent'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567

`initWithAccessToEntityTypes:` is Available in OS X v10.8 and later.

Comment: Actually it's about iOS and not OS X, but okay.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using a future version of the iOS SDK that isn't public yet. In order to make that work you'll have to use an unreleased version of Xcode that supports the new SDK. (Maybe it's **Xcode 4.5** you need to use?)

Please post to the Apple Developer Forum if you have questions regarding an unreleased SDK in the future!

Comment: This is not correct. The Apple docs state:Initialize an event store object with the initWithAccessToEntityTypes: method. Acceptable entity types are EKEntityMaskEvent for events and EKEntityMaskReminder for reminders.

Availability 
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Comment: In the documentation of iOS 6?! It's a new method and reminders are not even accessible prior to iOS 6. Don't say I'm wrong if I'm not, please: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: In the documentation of iOS5. I do not have the iOS6 SDK installed, only the 5.1.  It is in IOS 5.1 Library -> Core Services Layer -> EventKit -> EKEventStore Class Reference.
Xcode 4.4.1 here btw.

Comment: I'm sorry, we're both right and wrong at the same time. `initWithAccessToEntityTypes:` is only available on OS X (it **has been** in one of the iOS 6 betas), but it's mentioned in the iOS 5 documentation of EKEventStore, though it's not a publicly accessible method.